# App store submission using Xcode 8.1

Tags: xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

I found the below content from the link https://developer.apple.com/testflight/release-notes/.

**Starting May 10, 2017, app archives built with Xcode 8.3 will no longer be accepted. Make sure to build and submit your apps using Xcode 8.3.1 or later.**

What does they mean?. I cannot submit the apps using lower(than 8.3.1) XCode version?.I'm using 8.1 as of now,with 8.1 I cannot submit the apps to app store?

Answer (score 1):

**What does they mean?. I cannot submit the apps using lower(than 8.3.1) XCode version?.I'm using 8.1 as of now,with 8.1 I cannot submit the apps to app store?**

-> **You can submit builds using Xcode 6.0 or later or application loader 3.0 or later.** Starting May 10, 2017, **app archives built with Xcode 8.3** will no longer be accepted. It specifically says with **built 8.3 not allowed**.

Either Apple needs to update this release notes or update on ItunesConnect. I have recently submitted an build with 8.1 which was uploaded successfully on iTunes

Please see screenshot from ItunesConnect

[image]